# Bash - How to find files with certain names and set them as a variable?

Tags: bash

I am new to bash, and to stackoverflow, so please excuse me if my question is missing some elements.

I am looking for a way where I can read the files in the directory, and if the file name is in a specific format, set it to a certain variable to be processed.

For example: in /test, I have multiple files with the format: number_date_typeOfFile.fileType.

```
1_210720_TypeOne.txt
1_210721_TypeOne.txt
1_210722_TypeOne.txt
1_210720_TypeTwo.txt
1_210721_TypeTwo.txt
1_210722_TypeTwo.txt
+ other files
```

They are not going to be .txt files, its just as an example. There will be other files so I need a way that reads the front number, and the type correctly, with the varying dates.

The result I want is to set those 6 files into variables:

```
TypeOneA = 1_210720_TypeOne.txt
TypeOneB = 1_210721_TypeOne.txt
TypeOneC = 1_210722_TypeOne.txt
TypeTwoA = 1_210720_TypeTwo.txt
TypeTwoB = 1_210721_TypeTwo.txt
ect.
```

Other questions that are already answered seems to just read all the files in the directory and echo the name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would first create an array with all the file names you are interested in, and then process the array for creating the variables. The way you are going to name the variables makes me suspect that perhaps instead of having several variables with artificially created names, you may be better off having a single associative array with keys `OneB`, `OneC` etc.

Comment: BTW, unless you need the **complete** list of file names elsewhere, you perhaps don't even need the initial array. You just loop over all file names in question using something like  `for filename in directory/*` and build up your associative array in the loop body.

Comment: `I want is to set those 6 files into variables:` You want to set variables as a result? Why do you care about bash variables? `set it to a certain variable to be processed.` Seems variables are just means to an end. Don't set it to variables - just process the files. Are you asking XY question? How will you process the files?

Comment: @user1934428 yeah that was what I had in mind, I am not too sure how I would do that.

Comment: @KamilCuk the processing part is long and repetitive, so I would prefer to have them set by a variable. I also need to run this script for many different directories in same situation, so being able to set them in variables would help me not edit the code various times.

Comment: Sure, but what's the point. How will you use the variables? Do you want to process 3 files at a time?

Comment: @KamilCuk the point was to just access them without having to use the file name all the time, and to use the same script file in different directories with same naming patterns without editing it. Turns out I was looking for extended globbing.

Comment: @creamEarlyGrey:  _I am not too sure how I would do that._ How to do exactly **what**? Writing the loop or matching the respective parts of the filenames or filling the associative array? These are threeseparate problems. If you break down a task into sub-tasks, as it is usual in programming, ask a separate question for each subtask you can't solve, and show your own attempt. Then we have something to discuss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extended globbing can really help refine file sets.
If you set

```
shopt -s extglob
```

then you can match exactly that pattern with

```
[0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_Type+(One|Two).txt
```

or if you don't feel the need to specify *exactly* six digits in that "date" zone,

```
[0-9]_+([0-9])_Type+(One|Two).txt
```

This means you can collect them into an array safely with something like

```
shopt -s extglob
lst=( [0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_Type+(One|Two).txt )
```

The above will put them all into a single array. If you need separate arrays by type -

```
type1=( [0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_TypeOne.txt )
type2=( [0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_TypeTwo.txt )
```

Note that these don't even require extended globbing.

You can then access them like any array.

```
echo "${type1[5]}"
for t2 in "${type2[@]}"; do echo "$t2"; done
```

There are a lot of ways to tweak this.

```
$: shopt -s extglob
$: lst=( [0-9]_+([0-9])_*Type+(One|Two)*.txt )
```

Now it's one list with a more varied set of filenames.

```
$: cat <<< "${lst[@]}"
1_210720_TypeOne.txt 1_210720_TypeOne_210720123.txt 1_210720_TypeTwo.txt 
1_210721_TypeOne.txt 1_210721_TypeOne_210721456.txt 1_210721_TypeTwo.txt 
1_210722_TypeOne.txt 1_210722_TypeOne_210731789.txt 1_210722_TypeTwo.txt 
1_210723_RANDOMWORD_TypeOne_210723951.txt

$: printf "%s\n" "${lst[@]}" | grep TypeOne
1_210720_TypeOne.txt
1_210720_TypeOne_210720123.txt
1_210721_TypeOne.txt
1_210721_TypeOne_210721456.txt
1_210722_TypeOne.txt
1_210722_TypeOne_210731789.txt
1_210723_RANDOMWORD_TypeOne_210723951.txt

$: printf "%s\n" "${lst[@]}" | grep TypeTwo
1_210720_TypeTwo.txt
1_210721_TypeTwo.txt
1_210722_TypeTwo.txt

$: printf "%s\n" "${lst[@]}" | grep [^0-9]_TypeOne
1_210723_RANDOMWORD_TypeOne_210723951.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your input, to clarify, if I use extended globbing I will be able to put all the type ones into one array, and all the twos into another array, then I can point to each file by using index in the array? Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes. Edited. Does that answer your questions?

Comment: it does, perfectly. Thank you so much. One additional question on how to set them into lists: in some of the directories I found there are some files with just slightly different names, and I want them to be globbed up into the same list as others very similarly named, I was wondering how I could do this in the array defining step.

Comment: Example: 1_210720_TypeOne_210720123.txt
1_210721_TypeOne_210721456.txt
1_210722_TypeOne_210731789.txt and 1_210723_RANDOMWORD_TypeOne_210723951.txt. I would need all of them into the same list, I know I can just add the last one with one more line of code, but is there a way to get all four of them into the same array while changing the array defining step?

Comment: give me a bit to parse. :)

Comment: I dont see any new edits so I am not too sure what you are referring to when you say "that"

Comment: I had never hit the submit button, LOL! Sorry.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much, this helped me greatly. I wish I had enough reputation so I can upvote your answer. Thank you so so much.